# If the sum of $p$ terms of an A.P. is $4p^2+ 3p$, find its $n$'th term?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If the sum of $p$ terms of an A.P. is $4p^2+ 3p$,
find its $n$'th term ?

I have solved it and my answer is : $n$'th term = $(\frac{8p^2}n+\frac{6p}n)-a$

But I'm not sure is it correct or not. Please help ?

Comment: Show us your solution, then we can tell you if that's right. You should also tell what the $a$ that appears in solution is.

Comment: Why $-a$? The nth term should be expression a+(n-1)d,and...

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If $S_m$ denotes the sum of $m$ terms,

The $p$th term $T_p=S_p-S_{p-1}$

Answer (score 1):

(Unsure, if I went wrong please let me know where)

The sum of $p$ terms of an AP is given by $S_p=\frac{p}{2}(2a+(p-1)d)$

The $n$th term is given by $n_p=a+(n-1)d$

We know that $S_p=4p^2+3p$ so comparing to our formula above, we get:

$$\frac{p}{2}(2a+(p-1)d)=\frac{d}{2}p^2+(a-\frac{d}{2})p=4p^2+3p$$

Comparing coefficients of $p^2$ and $p$ we get:

$d/2=4$ so $d=8$ and $a-d/2=3$ so $a=7$

Therefore, the $n$th term is

$n_p=7+8(n-1)=8n-1$

Answer (score -1):

Sp = 4p^2 + 3p
S1 = 4 (1)^2 + 3 x 1 = 7
S2= 4(2)^2 + 3 x2 = 18
Now we know S2 = A1 (First Term) + A2 (Second Term)
So 20 = 7 + A2
and A2 = 20 - 7 = 13
D = A2 - A1 = 13 - 7 = 6
Anow we have a = 7 and D = 6
sp An = a + (n-1) d or 7+(n-1)6 or 7+6n-6 or 6n + 1 Answer